# ImageMagick converts svg file to xbm with artifacts and changed size

Tags: svg, imagemagick, image-manipulation

Trying to convert some icons from svg to xbm to display them with NodeMCU on OLED display.

Using this command: `mogrify -path ../src -format xbm  *.svg`

As You can see below  output is a bit unexpected. Also it changes width and height, so from 16x16 svg it produces 15x15 xbm.

How to preserve original size and get rid of this artifacts?

- Inkscape 0.92.4
- ImageMagick 6.9.7-4 Q16 x86_64 20170114
- elementary os 5.0 (Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS)

[image]

Comment: Post a link to your SVG input file. What SVG renderer are you using with Imagemagick: MSVG/XML, RSVG delegate or Inkscape. The latter works better than the Imagemagick internal MSVG/XML. Imagemagick will use Inkscape as preference if it is on your system (at least for more current versions). You can see the former two from `convert -list format` and look at the end of the SVG line. Try convert rather than mogrify and see if you still get the wrong size.

Comment: Hello, @fmw42 you can check the svg here: https://github.com/stsdc/oled-icons

I don't really know what renderer Imagemagick uses. Inkscape is installed.

Comment: `convert Unknown.svg Unknown.png` looks fine to me using IM 6.9.9.40 Q16 Mac OSX with Inkscape renderer

Comment: `convert` doesn't works for me. I do still have these artifacts. Please note that I'm trying to convert to *.xbm not *.png

Comment: Did you check which SVG renderer you are using as I suggested? What version of Imagemagick? What platform?

Comment: Looks fine to me as output to xbm, also. It is 16x16 pixels. I suggest you install Inkscape and try again.

Comment: Inkscape 0.92.4

ImageMagick 6.9.7-4 Q16 x86_64 20170114 

Ubuntu 18.04.2

Comment: Your Imagemagick version is ancient. The date of the versions is nearly 3 years old. I suggest you upgrade. Current IM 6 is 6.9.10.77. I was also using Inkscape 0.92.4. Note that on Linux, they often only update for security and not always for all the bug fixes. So you could have a version that did not properly use Inkscape or perhaps Inkscape install is bad.

Comment: Can confirm, that updating to latest Imagemagick is the solution. I will mark your answer as solution if You will add info about updating. Thank You very much.

Comment: What info about updating do you want?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using Imagemagick 6.9.10.77 Q16 Mac OSX Sierra with SVG renderer Inkscape 0.92.4, I get:

```
convert Unknown.svg Unknown.xbm
```

Here is the result expanded for viewing and showing a size of 16x16 pixels.

[image]

I suspect that if you upgrade your version of Imagemagick so that it properly uses Inkscape, that it might work correctly to convert your SVG file.